Sending an audio recording from js to an actix-web server to save to disk
Currently trying to send some recorded audio from the browser to an actix-web server, and trying to save it to disk in a manner that results in a playable track from a generic media player. I am finding this difficult to do, especially because I have never worked with media before. I am basing whatever I am doing on. a combination of some googling and some GPTing.
The problem: A file does seem to be saved to disk. It is a non-zero size file however it does not seem playable in VLC media player.
The script to send the recording to the actix-web server:
const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/mp3" });
  const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const audio = new Audio(audioURL);

  // create a button
  let button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  // creating text to be
  //displayed on button
  let text = document.createTextNode("Play recording ", audio_rec_num + 1);
  button.appendChild(text);
  button.setAttribute("num", audio_rec_num);

  audio_rec_num++;
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let num = Number(button.getAttribute("num"));

    // audio_chunks[num].play();

    // Create FormData object to send the audio data
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("audio", blob, "recorded_audio.mp3");

    // Send the audio data to the server using fetch or XMLHttpRequest
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/track_sample", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log("Audio sent successfully");
        } else {
          console.error("Failed to send audio");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error sending audio: ", error);
      });
  });

The handler receiving the data:
async fn track_sampler(req_body: web::Bytes) -> impl Responder {
println!("track sampler hit");
let audio_data = req_body.to_vec();
println!("Received audio data with length: {}", audio_data.len());

// Save the audio data to a WAV file
let file_path = "received_audio.mp3";
let mut file = match File::create(file_path) {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(_) => return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish(),
};

// Write the bytes of the audio file to the file on disk
if let Err(_) = file.write_all(&audio_data) {
    return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish();
}
println!("done");
// Return a success response
HttpResponse::Ok().body("Audio file uploaded successfully")

}
I just need some clear pointers to be able to implement this. I don't necessarily need code, but that could be super helpful as well. What am I doing wrong ? I know I am saving it incorrectly, but how do it 'correctly' ?
Note : I do not wish to save the audio to disk directly from the JS

The body is going to be encoded as form data as indicated in the JS, but you're just taking all of the bytes of the body and stuffing them into a file.

The JavaScript FormData type encodes the body as "multipart/form-data". It is not simply your raw file bytes. To decode this body in your Actix-Web handler, you'll want to use actix-multipart.
The simple way to use it would be to use a derive macro on a struct reflecting the form data.

Use actix_multipart::form::bytes::Bytes to store the bytes in memory:
use actix_multipart::form::MultipartForm;
use actix_multipart::form::bytes::Bytes;

#[derive(MultipartForm)]
struct TrackUpload {
    audio: Bytes,
}


Or use actix_multipart::form::tempfile::TempFile to store it immediately to disk:
use actix_multipart::form::MultipartForm;
use actix_multipart::form::tempfile::TempFile;

#[derive(MultipartForm)]
struct TrackUpload {
    audio: TempFile,
}


See the documentation on #[derive(MultipartForm)] for more options.


And then use it in your handler like so:
use actix_multipart::form::MultipartForm;

async fn track_sampler(MultipartForm(upload): MultipartForm<TrackUpload>) -> impl Responder {
    // use upload.audio
}

There is also the option to accept actix_multipart::Multipart into your handler to handle the field and content streaming more manually than the above technique if that is required.
